# how to close an IPv6 connection in golang

Tags: go

The code below is my tcpserver about accepting connections. After running a while, there're lots of *established IPv6 connection* left in the system.

```
func (s *TCPServer) serve() {
    tcpaddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", s.Addr)
    s.listener, err = net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpaddr)
    for {
        conn, err := s.listener.AcceptTCP()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        conn.SetReadBuffer(s.ReadBufferSize)
        conn.SetWriteBuffer(s.WriteBufferSize)

        s.wg.Add(1)
        go s.handle(conn)
    }
}

func (s *TCPServer) handle(conn net.Conn) {
    defer s.wg.Done()
    defer func() {
        conn.Close()
        fmt.Println("Conn Closed", conn.RemoteAddr())
    }()

    s.ClientHandler(conn, s.closed)
}
```

using go1.8.1, runs under ubuntu 16.04

My questions are:

1. why IPv6 connection is not closed?(using `lsof | grep program | grep -i IPv6` show lots of established IPv6 connection.)
2. how to close this `net.Conn` from `listener.AcceptTCP()` correctly?

--edit--client handler will call the following code.

```
func HandleClient(conn net.Conn, readDeadline, writeDeadline int, op *Config) {

    header := make([]byte, 2)

    for {
        conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Duration(readDeadline) * time.Second))
        conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Duration(writeDeadline) * time.Second))

        n, err := io.ReadFull(conn, header)
        if err == io.EOF {
            return
        }

        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        size := binary.BigEndian.Uint16(header)
        payload := make([]byte, size)
        n, err = io.ReadFull(conn, payload)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        err = client.WriteIn(payload) // decode the content of the packet
        if err == ErrorKickedOut {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the clients ever closing the connection? What status are the connections in (shown in `lsof`)?

Comment: I it possible that `ClientHandler` doesn't return and deferred function isn't called? We don't have `ClientHandler` code to look at.

Comment: You close an ipv6 connection like any other, by calling Close. If they're not closed, it means `ClientHandler` isn't returning. What are the clients? What does `ClientHandler` do? Do you have reasonable timeouts set for all operations?

Comment: 1. the status of connection is established in ```lsof``` 2. If this connection is IPv4, seems like closed 3. heartbeat used to close idle connection

Comment: Next step is to look at your stack trace and see where these connections are blocked.

Comment: After some digging: 1. IPv6 connection from mobile phone client  IPv4 connection from pc client  2. call ```conn.Close()``` would close connection no matter IPv4 or IPv6 3. so much IPv6 connection linger caused by 90% connections from mobile phone client. and the heartbeat time is too long after ```listener.Accept()```, shorten heartbeat interval reduced 30-50% linger connection.